# Query being executed beyond timeout in a transaction Oracle

Tags: performance, oracle-11g-r2, query-performance

I have a simple query as below when executed separately the result is coming very quickly. But when is part of the application flow the same query is being shown as in execution status for more than 5 minutes and finally getting timeout, causing the transaction rollback. What could be the reason which is causing it to execute for that long when it is perfectly alright individually? Are there are any deadlocks happening? If so, the error message is not showing any such details, it is simply saying that transaction timeout. Our DBA also saying that the query is perfectly alright.

```
SELECT 
  t0_bean.PLCY_PRD_PREM_DRV_ID
FROM
  POLICY_PERIOD_PREMIUM_DRV t0_bean,
  POLICY_PERIOD t1_bean_policyPeriodCMR
WHERE
  (t1_bean_policyPeriodCMR.PLCY_PRD_ID = :1
  AND t0_bean.JUR_TYP_CD = :2
  AND t0_bean.PREM_TYP_CD = :3
  AND t0_bean.RT_ELEM_TYP_CD = :4
  AND t0_bean.VOID_IND = 'n'
  AND t0_bean.PLCY_PRD_ID=t1_bean_policyPeriodCMR.PLCY_PRD_ID)
```

Comment: Waiting for 5 minutes on what **wait event**? Are the execution plan, bind values and client environment (NLS) identical for the manual and the application runs?

Comment: I could not identify the wait event. Can you please let me know how to check for that? Yes, execution plan and bind values are exactly the same in both the cases. I have actually captured the raw SQL from application flow and executed manually. So it is exactly the same.

Comment: You can find the wait event in the EVENT column of V$SESSION. However this is useful only if your session is waiting for the same event (EVENT + SEQ#)for a long time (SECONDS_IN_WAIT), otherwise it will just change too fast, and you need to sample it. At this point it would be better to turn on SQL trace and see what actually is happening during those runs. If you have access to Enterprise Manager and you are licensed to use the Tuning Pack, you can also follow the execution with Real-Time SQL Monitoring.

Comment: It is constantly waiting on "db file sequential read" for 5 minutes and getting timeout after that. What does this event mean. I have only two tables involved in the query and there are proper indexes defined on it.